# how to sort by english date format not american pandas .sort()

Tags: python, sorting, date, pandas, datetime

```
    symb                dates
4     BLK  01/03/2014 09:00:00
0     BBR  02/06/2014 09:00:00
21     HZ  02/06/2014 09:00:00
24   OMNI  02/07/2014 09:00:00
31   NOTE  03/04/2014 09:00:00
65    AMP  03/04/2016 09:00:00
40    RBY  04/07/2014 09:00:00
```

Here's a sample of the output from (`df.sort('date')`).

As you can see it uses the days for the months and vice versa. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Read dd/mm/yyyy date-format correctly in `pandas read_csv`, at read-time. Use options `parse_dates`, and you'll want `dayfirst = True`. Like most problems using `read_csv`, the solution is use the right options to get the `read_csv` right the first time, rather than fix it up afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and use the format argument then sort it.

```
>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
>> df.sort('date')

               date    symb
0 2014-01-03 09:00:00   BLK
1 2014-02-06 09:00:00   BBR
2 2014-02-06 09:00:00    HZ
3 2014-02-07 09:00:00  OMNI
4 2014-03-04 09:00:00  NOTE
6 2014-04-07 09:00:00   RBY
5 2016-03-04 09:00:00   AMP
```

Comment: Please be aware - the `.sort()` method is deprecated, use `.sort_values()` instead

Comment: @MaxU Good point, seen the warning but left it as is not to cause confusion since OP uses .sort().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), for sorting [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
#format mm/dd/YYYY
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
print (df.sort_values('dates'))
    symb               dates
4    BLK 2014-01-03 09:00:00
0    BBR 2014-02-06 09:00:00
21    HZ 2014-02-06 09:00:00
24  OMNI 2014-02-07 09:00:00
31  NOTE 2014-03-04 09:00:00
40   RBY 2014-04-07 09:00:00
65   AMP 2016-03-04 09:00:00
```

---

```
#format dd/mm/YYYY
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], dayfirst=True)
print (df.sort_values('dates'))
    symb               dates
4    BLK 2014-03-01 09:00:00
31  NOTE 2014-04-03 09:00:00
0    BBR 2014-06-02 09:00:00
21    HZ 2014-06-02 09:00:00
24  OMNI 2014-07-02 09:00:00
40   RBY 2014-07-04 09:00:00
65   AMP 2016-04-03 09:00:00
```

Another solution is use parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), if format `dd/mm/YYYY` add `dayfirst=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""symb,dates
BLK,01/03/2014 09:00:00
BBR,02/06/2014 09:00:00
HZ,02/06/2014 09:00:00
OMNI,02/07/2014 09:00:00
NOTE,03/04/2014 09:00:00
AMP,03/04/2016 09:00:00
RBY,04/07/2014 09:00:00"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['dates'])

print (df)
   symb               dates
0   BLK 2014-01-03 09:00:00
1   BBR 2014-02-06 09:00:00
2    HZ 2014-02-06 09:00:00
3  OMNI 2014-02-07 09:00:00
4  NOTE 2014-03-04 09:00:00
5   AMP 2016-03-04 09:00:00
6   RBY 2014-04-07 09:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
symb             object
dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```
print (df.sort_values('dates'))
   symb               dates
0   BLK 2014-01-03 09:00:00
1   BBR 2014-02-06 09:00:00
2    HZ 2014-02-06 09:00:00
3  OMNI 2014-02-07 09:00:00
4  NOTE 2014-03-04 09:00:00
6   RBY 2014-04-07 09:00:00
5   AMP 2016-03-04 09:00:00
```

---

```
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['dates'], dayfirst=True)

print (df)
   symb               dates
0   BLK 2014-03-01 09:00:00
1   BBR 2014-06-02 09:00:00
2    HZ 2014-06-02 09:00:00
3  OMNI 2014-07-02 09:00:00
4  NOTE 2014-04-03 09:00:00
5   AMP 2016-04-03 09:00:00
6   RBY 2014-07-04 09:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
symb             object
dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

print (df.sort_values('dates'))
   symb               dates
0   BLK 2014-03-01 09:00:00
4  NOTE 2014-04-03 09:00:00
1   BBR 2014-06-02 09:00:00
2    HZ 2014-06-02 09:00:00
3  OMNI 2014-07-02 09:00:00
6   RBY 2014-07-04 09:00:00
5   AMP 2016-04-03 09:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting the data, but if you are importing it from some source such as a CSV you could use pandas.read_csv and set `parse_dates=True`. The question is what is the type of the **dates** column? You an easily change them to datelike objects using `dateutil.parse.parse. For example,

```
import pandas
import dateutil
data = {'symb': ['BLK', 'BBR', 'HZ', 'OMNI', 'NOTE', 'AMP', 'RBY'],
        'dates': ['01/03/2014 09:00:00', '02/06/2014 09:00:00', '02/06/2014 09:00:00',
               '02/07/2014 09:00:00', '03/04/2014 09:00:00', '03/04/2016 09:00:00',
               '04/07/2014 09:00:00']}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.dates = df.dates.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
print df.to_string()

# OUTPUT
# 0 2014-01-03 09:00:00   BLK
# 1 2014-02-06 09:00:00   BBR
# 2 2014-02-06 09:00:00    HZ
# 3 2014-02-07 09:00:00  OMNI
# 4 2014-03-04 09:00:00  NOTE
# 5 2016-03-04 09:00:00   AMP
# 6 2014-04-07 09:00:00   RBY
```

This gets you the [ISO8601 format] which may be preferable to the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but if you must have that format you can use the code recommended by @umutto