# How to sort dates imported from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to write a program that can print a list of sorted dates but it keeps sorting by the 'day' instead of the full date, day,month,year

Im very new to python so theres probably a lot i'm doing wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.
So I have it so that you can view the list over two pages. 
the dates will sort 
12/03/2004
13/08/2001
15/10/2014
but I need the full date sorted

```
df = pd.read_csv('Employee.csv')
df = df.sort_values('Date of Employment.')
List1 = df.iloc[:50, 1:]
List2 = df.iloc[50:99, 1:]
```

Comment: That's probably because you are reading the 'Date of Employment.' column as a string, so you should convert the values to date first, possibly using datetime.strptime and after converting the sorting should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort by english date format not american pandas .sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359603/how-to-sort-by-english-date-format-not-american-pandas-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3//library/datetime.html#module-datetime) data type has to be used for the dates to be sorted correctly**

You need to use either one of these approaches to convert the dates to datetime objects:

## Approach 1

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['Date of Employment.'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of Employment.']')
```

## Approach 2

You can parse the dates at the same time that the Pandas DataFrame is being loaded:

`df = pd.read_csv('Employee.csv', parse_dates=['Date of Employement.'])`

This is equivalent to the first approach with the exception that everything is done in one step.

---

Next you need to sort the datetime values in either ascending or descending order.

## Ascending:

```
`df.sort_values('Date of Employment.')`
```

## Descending

```
`df.sort_values('Date of Employment.',ascending=False)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert Date of Employment. to a Date before sorting

```
df['Date of Employment.'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of Employment.'],format= '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Otherwise it's just strings for Python