# Why are my dates not being sorted correctly?

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe and want to sort it by dates.

[image]

The format here is dd/mm/yyyy. As you can see it is not sorted correctly. I guess I need to change the format of my dates.
How can I get this dataframe sorted so that it looks like:

01/05/2020

02/05/2020

03/05/2020

etc.

Comment: Maybe this solution will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359727/3642398 ?

Comment: The argument  dayfirst=True fixed the problem.